# Email sending issue with “localhost.localdomain”

Tags: email, sendmail

I have a DigitalOcean server which runs Ubuntu 14.04. I am having problems with sending emails from the PHP `mail()` function (which uses `sendmail` internally).

I think the issue may be related to my `hosts` file config. Here is what I have in `/etc/hosts` at the moment:

`127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx`

And in `etc/hostname`:

`ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx`

(In the above two, I replaced the IP address digits with `x`)

Now I have a domain pointing to this server, let's call this `mydomain.com`.

So when my website `mydomain.com` sends an email, the email is going in to the junk mail folder. I ran a test on https://www.mail-tester.com and one of the issues it flags up is:

[image]

I have tried adding `mydomain.com` to the line above in the `hosts` file but this results in the email arriving after a long time or not arriving at all.

Here are the Received headers:

```
Received: from localhost.localdomain (unknown [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx])
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher xxx (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by mail-tester.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id xxx
    for <test-xxx@mail-tester.com>; Mon, 29 Apr 2019 18:35:18 +0200 (CEST)

Received: from localhost.localdomain (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by localhost.localdomain (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-3) with ESMTP id xxx
    for <test-xxx@mail-tester.com>; Mon, 29 Apr 2019 17:35:18 +0100

Received: from mydomain.com (www-data@localhost)
    by localhost.localdomain (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) with SMTP id xxx
    for <test-xxx@mail-tester.com>; Mon, 29 Apr 2019 17:35:18 +0100
```

Can someone please advise what the issue may be and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody cares about hops inside your infrastructure and how many localhosts are passed. But be sure to let your outgoing server say "Hello, I'm mail.domain.tld" instead of "Hello, I'm localhost.localdomain", because no halfway properly configured server will be interested to talk to unknown mailservers.

I see in your referenced headers that you use `postfix(1)` for processing outbound emails.
Look for the variable `myhostname` inside your `main.cf` (usually located in `/etc/postfix` or `/usr/local/etc/postfix`) and fill it properly.
Example: `myhostname=mail.domain.tld` (replace it with your mailservers name). Also be sure that `smtp_banner=` contains at least `$myhostname` like `smtp_banner=$myhostname ESMTP Postfix`.

See [this](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) for additional info.

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks for your answer. I don't intentionally use Postfix - at one point I did have Postfix installed on the server but then I removed it as I no longer needed it. It seems it was not fully removed and is still being referenced somewhere. This is probably one of the causes of the issue. I only want to use `sendmail`. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: You either have to configure it, for example, to use a *smarthost*, or install another (minimal) sendmail implementation, like `msmtp` or `ssmtp`, who is only able to use a smarthost. The installation will invoke `update-alternatives` or something like this, so the sendmail executable used by `mail()` will be replaced with the one from a new package. **A warning note here:** never try to "just send mail" nowadays, always use a properly configured mail server. It is then called *a smarthost*. You can even use public services, like Gmail for that.